# How do I access AIP_STORAGE_URI in Vertex AI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I uploaded a model with

```
gcloud beta ai models upload --artifact-uri
```

And in the docker I access `AIP_STORAGE_URI`.
I see that `AIP_STORAGE_URI` is another Google Storage location so I try to download the files using `storage.Client()` but then it says that I don't have access:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/caip-tenant-***-***-*-*-***?projection=noAcl&prettyPrint=false: custom-online-prediction@**.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket
```

I am running this endpoint with the default service account.

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/custom-container-requirements#artifacts

According to the above link:
`The service account that your container uses by default has permission to read from this URI.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind the error being, the default service account that Vertex AI uses has the “[Storage Object Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles)” role which excludes the `storage.buckets.get` permission. At the same time, the `storage.Client()` part of the code makes a `storage.buckets.get` request to the Vertex AI managed bucket for which the default service account does not have permission to.

To resolve the issue, I would suggest you to follow the below steps -

1. Make changes in the custom code to access the bucket with the model artifacts in your project instead of using the environment variable `AIP_STORAGE_URI` which points to the model location in the Vertex AI managed bucket.
2. Create your own service account and grant the service account with all the [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/custom-service-account) needed by the custom code. For this specific error, a role with the `storage.buckets.get` permission, eg. [Storage Admin](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles) ("roles/storage.admin") has to be granted to the service account.
3. Provide the newly created service account in the "Service Account" field when deploying the model.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Google documentation, it says the model's container by default has access to the different bucket where Vertex AI stores the model artifacts. In your python script, or wherever, you can use the gcloud command to install the model artifact without running `gcloud init` or doing any sort of authorization.

Here is an example of how to download model artifacts in a python script using the AIP_STORAGE_URI:

```
# Loading the model from the pickle file
AIP_STORAGE_URI = os.environ.get('AIP_STORAGE_URI')
command = f"gcloud storage cp '{AIP_STORAGE_URI}/model.pkl' model.pkl"
subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    model = pickle.load(file)
```

Make sure you have gcloud CLI installed in your Docker image.